# Images disappearing from assets folder in Xcode

Tags: xcode, assets

Recently, I've been getting some pretty bizarre behavior in Xcode that I haven't been able to find the root cause of. Whenever I open close and open my project, I find that images from my assets folder have been deleted. Xcode then gives me the warning that "The file ... for the image set ... does not exist." The problem went away for a while and then recently it's started happening again.

It's becoming pretty tedious adding the images over and over again and I'm not really sure how to solve this problem.

Edit:

I've noticed that the .pdf files within the assets directory in finder have been deleted. Could it be an issue with how source control is managing the files?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you on? I remember that happening to me a long while back, I think I was on Xcode 8.x or 9.x. Can't say I have seen that with the newer versions.

Comment: @rasulfahad I'm on Xcode 14, not sure why it's still happening. What worked for you then?

Comment: Nothing really. It stopped happening after I upgraded. I am sure it has not happened since Xcode 12 at least. Sorry.